# Gwt image button using uibinder

Tags: java, gwt

How do you create an image button in GWT using the uibinder. My current code looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE ui:UiBinder SYSTEM "http://dl.google.com/gwt/DTD/xhtml.ent">
<ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui="urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder"
    xmlns:g="urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui">
    <ui:with type="com.test.client.Resources" field="res"></ui:with>
    <g:HTMLPanel>   
        <g:Image resource="{res.facebook_32}"/>
        <g:PushButton>
            <g:downFace image="{res.facebook_32}"></g:downFace>
            <g:upFace image="{res.facebook_32}"></g:upFace>
        </g:PushButton>
    </g:HTMLPanel>
</ui:UiBinder>
```

The image is printed correctly so the image resource works correctly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What is the objective here? A regular image can behave as a button. Is it the events you are after?

Comment: Check, that works. Only the arrow doesn't change to the 'click hand'.